# Chrome Extension - declarativeNetRequest delayed when I call the function "updateDynamicRules"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

this is my func:
`

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules(
    (rulesetSets) => {
        oldIds = getRuleIdsFromList(rulesetSets);
        newRules = readNewRulesFromProfile(oldIds);
        newIds = getRuleIdsFromList(newRules);
        console.log('-----------------');
        console.log(oldIds)
        console.log(newIds)
        console.log(newRules)
        finalRules = {
            removeRuleIds: oldIds,
            addRules: newRules
        }
        excUpdateRules(finalRules);
    }
)



function excUpdateRules(rules) {
    console.log('update rule success');
    console.log(rules);
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(rules, () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(JSON.stringify(chrome.runtime.lastError));
        } else {
            console.log('update rule success');
        }
    });
}
```

`
when I reload it , and I call getDynamicRules and I got the prev rules. not the rules I set just now.
why this happens and what should I do to make it works right now

I call getDynamicRules and I got the rules set just now

Comment: Show us how and where exactly you call getDynamicRules after updateDynamicRules. Note that this method is asynchronous, so you must `await` it or use its callback.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just call it when I click a button in the popup.html, and I alert the rules.

Comment: Since timing is important you need to show the exact code to make this answerable.

Comment: @wOxxOm `function showNowRules() {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.getDynamicRules(
        (rulesetSets) => {
            console.log('=============================');
            console.log('showNowRules:');
            console.log(rulesetSets);
            alert(JSON.stringify(rulesetSets));
        }
    )
}`

Comment: You need to make an [MCVE](/help/mcve) i.e. a complete sequence or code that demonstrates the problem. Note that it may be a bug in Chrome, to report which you will also need to provide a reproducible sequence.